# Применение триггера к нескольким столбцам таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Есть таблица в которую вносятся следующие данные:

```
CREATE TABLE master.dbo.Actavia (
  Id int IDENTITY,
  НО nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [Дата НО] date NULL,
  ВО nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [Дата ВО] date NULL,
  ГИ nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [Дата ГИ] date NULL,
  ТО nvarchar(50) NULL,
  [Дата ТО] date NULL,
  [Описание] nvarchar(max) NULL
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Для заполнения столбца НО необходимым "номером" на основании Id имеется триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumNOtrigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET НО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.Vi')
GO
```

Как реализовать внесение в столбцы ВО, ГИ, ТО  "номеров" по схожей схеме?
Например:

```
  ВО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.Ve')
    ГИ= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.H')
    ТО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.T')
```

Comment: Ставите запятую и добавляете нужное поле для изменения. Обычный update по сути

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставите запятую и добавляете нужное поле для изменения. Обычный update по сути

```
CREATE TRIGGER NumNOtrigger1
ON dbo.Actavia
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Actavia
SET НО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.Vi'),
    ВО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.Ve'),
    ГИ= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.H'),
    ТО= CONCAT('R.', Id, '.T')
GO
```

Comment: Пробовал так. К сожалению, ругается "Object has invalid source and cannot be saved" на всё что идёт после первой запятой

Comment: Вопрос снят. Спасибо. Это dbForge почему-то предвзят к таким записям, Visual Studio зажевал как положено.